# Matplotlib: move Origin to upper left corner

Tags: python, matplotlib, matlab-figure

In Matlab, the plot is to be made such that origin is on top-left corner, x-axis is positive south to the origin, y-axis is positive east to the origin; x-axis is numbered on the left margin and y-axis is labelled on the top margin.

```
figure();
set(gca,'YAxisLocation','Right','YDir','reverse')
axis([0 10 0 10]);
daspect([1,1,1])
grid on
view([-90 -90])
```

How to achieve the same in Python? I proceeded like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)

plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 0.03])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

What is the python equivalent for:

1. `set(gca,'YAxisLocation','Right','YDir','reverse')`
2. `daspect([1,1,1])`
3. `view([-90 -90])`

**EDIT:**

```
figure
set(gca,'YAxisLocation','right','XTick',0:15,'YDir','reverse')
axis([0 16 0 16]);
daspect([1,1,1])
hold on
text(2,8,'CHN');
text(8,2,'USA');
view([-90 -90])
```

Output is:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an commented Example that shows how you can invert the axis and move the ticks to the top, set the grid state and imitate the view() command:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()    
plt.axis([0, 16, 0, 16])     
plt.grid(False)                         # set the grid
data= [(8,2,'USA'), (2,8,'CHN')]

for obj in data:
    plt.text(obj[1],obj[0],obj[2])      # change x,y as there is no view() in mpl


ax=plt.gca()                            # get the axis
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])        # invert the axis
ax.xaxis.tick_top()                     # and move the X-Axis      
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 16, 1)) # set y-ticks
ax.yaxis.tick_left()                    # remove right y-Ticks
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: I am using `matplotlib` rather than `pylab`. Could you give your answer in terms of `matplotlib` or is it same?

Comment: Yup, that's great. Also i want to view the graph in a special way (i want to view the graph from below the x-y plane generated by your code, with my head in west direction and foot in east), as i said in my question. In Matlab, i know that `view([-90 -90])` does the trick. What to do in Python?

Comment: Could you show me a sample plot with data before and after the view transformation? I can´t quiet get how it should look. In general you can take the plt.axis( [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] ) command to change the viewport. For Example: Just exchange xmin and xmax for a flip around the y-Axis .

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late. So i have put a short Matlab code. Your python code also gives almost identical result but could you modify your code to give the exact output as the Matlab code in Edit section?

Comment: I updated my answer. Unfortunatly there is nothing like the view() command afaik. You can imitate that by switching your data though.

Comment: You can invert the yaxis with `ax.invert_yaxis()`.